# Am trying to read a population_data.json file but when ever i run the code it doesn't display any data in the file and i don't get any Error too?

Tags: python-3.7

```py
import json

#Load the data into a list.
filename = 'population_data.json'
with open(filename)as f:`enter code here`
    pop_data = json.load(f)

    enter code here

#Print the 2010 population data for each country.
for pop_dict in pop_data:`enter code here`
    if pop_dict['Year'] == '2010':
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
        population = int(float(pop_dict['Value']))
        print(country_name + " : " + str(population))
```

Am trying to extract data from a population_data.json file, but whenever i run my code it doesn't show any result and i don't get any Errors, i have save the population data file in the same folder with the code but i still have that same problem, i don't get any result of the data in the shell. i would be glad if someone can help.Thank you .

```
    enter code here
import json

#Load the data into a list.
filename = 'population_data.json'
with open(filename)as f:`enter code here`
    pop_data = json.load(f)

    enter code here

#Print the 2010 population data for each country.
for pop_dict in pop_data:`enter code here`
    if pop_dict['Year'] == '2010':
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
        population = int(float(pop_dict['Value']))
        print(country_name + " : " + str(population))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest starting your script in the python **debugger** (pdb). You can start it either by starting your script like this:

```
python3 -m pdb your_script.py
```

or by importing the pdb module. Adding the following line into your python file (for example after `import json`, or any other):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Once it is loaded, the debugger stops at the first instruction and shows the debugger promt `(Pdb)` . Continue execution line by line by typing `next` and hitting `ENTER` until you hit a line where something interesting is happening. The debugger prints always the **next** instruction and the script path and line.

Debugger output is added below, **everything after** `(Pdb)` you have to type and confirm with `ENTER`

```
(Pdb) next
> /path/to/your_script.py(7)<module>()
-> pop_data = json.load(f)
(Pdb) next
> /path/to/your_script.py(11)<module>()
-> for pop_dict in pop_data:
```

Now let the debugger print contents of a variable

```
(Pdb) p pop_data
{"Probably": "something", "you": "don't expect here"}
```

I suspect either the for loop yields  0 `pop_dict`s and therefore the loop body is never executed, or no `pop_dict` key `Year` has value `2010` and the `if` body is never executed.

**Alternative** to type next often (== single stepping): set a `break` point on a specific line (`your_script.py:11`), and `continue` execution until the breakpoint is hit

```
(Pdb) break your_script.py:11
Breakpoint 1 at /path/to/your_script.py:11
(Pdb) continue
> /path/to/your_script.py(11)<module>()
-> for pop_dict in pop_data:
(Pdb)
```

For additional debugger commands see [pdb commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands)

Comment: I just tried importing the pdb module, i can't really understand how the debugger works, can you please explain a step by step way of debugger with pdb. i just read a little about it on can't seem to understand....Thank you !

Comment: @AbubakariUmarblacKrussainUma How do you start your code (IDE, terminal)? Is it a simple script (one file) or part of a module (multiple files)? Also see answer edits

Comment: I run most of my codes from the terminal and yes its a simple script.I had import the json module  to load data into list ,but it won't show the data when i run the code in the terminal(shell).Thank your for assistance. I look forward to you helping me solve this problem.